# Android Studio downloads .pom plugins on every build

Tags: android, android-studio, build

Android Studio ver. 3.6.3 (latest stable release as of this writing) downloads a whole bunch of .pom plugins on *every* build. Even if I don't change one byte in my sources or resources but hit the Build button again, it takes forever (now that the Internet is slower due to the pandemic) to download things like:

```
Build: Download google-services-4.3.3.pom...
Build: Download jetifier-processor-1.0.0-beta08.pom...
Build: Download bundletool-0.10.3.pom...
Build: Download jetifier-processor-1.0.0-beta08.pom... (again... then often fails)
etc. etc. on each build.
```

I submitted a bug to the Issue Tracker, giving more details there and even posting a video of a build process: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154178296, but so far no help. I discovered the issue originally with Android Studio version 3.6.2, today came an update to 3.6.3, but no change in this respect.

Long build times due to unnecessary downloads of all the "plugins" greatly affect productivity, when a lot of building and testing is necessary. Is there any setting in Android Studio that I could apply to avoid these downloads?

Comment: you can use gradle offline mode, you just have to enabled when you add new dependency, else it works fine.

Comment: Thank you, Ashish, it works. Had trouble finding this setting, as apparently in Android Studio 3.6 it changed: "New location to toggle Gradle's offline mode To enable or disable Gradle's offline mode, first select View > Tool Windows > Gradle from the menu bar. Then, near the top of the Gradle window, click Toggle Offline Mode Gradle offline button in the Gradle panel."